# How to Delete selected row in gridview in vb.net by clicking on delete button

Tags: vb.net, gridview

This code below was to delete first row and not selected row.

```
Protected Sub LinkBtn_Del_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim intpartID As Integer = gvParticipant.DataKeys(0).Value
        Dim comPart As New SqlCommand("usp_Participant_Delete", consql)
        comPart.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        comPart.Parameters.Add("@ParID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intpartID
        consql.Open()
        comPart.ExecuteNonQuery()
        consql.Close()
        selectParticipant()
        MultiViewall.SetActiveView(viewDisplayWorkshop)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing 0 when calling the DataKeys() method, you should get the selected index of your GridView. In your case, simply use gvParticipant.SelectedIndex

[GridView.SelectedIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)